# How do I enforce an auto increment in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, auto-increment

I can create an auto increment by setting a sequence and setting a tables column default value to be that sequence, but I can still manually enter a value that is not that sequence. How can I enforce a constraint to this on insert? Is using a trigger the only way?

Comment: `create table test (id serial not null primary key, payload varchar);`

Comment: @wildplasser: that's essentially what Alexander did and it **will** allow providing values for the `id` column manually. Using a trigger is the only way to avoid that

Comment: Aha, OP wants to *forbid* manual entry of the value. I must have misunderstood the question. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

Ive tested this and you can insert the primary key as long as its UNIQUE. If its Null the auto sequence kicks in (**tablename_colname_seq**) and inserts a UNIQUE primary key.

```
-- Table: test
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;


CREATE TABLE foo( primary_id int not null UNIQUE default  nextval('tablename_colname_seq'),

a_nother int ) 
WITH ( OIDS=FALSE );
```

ALTER TABLE foo
  OWNER TO postgres;

-- Test Data

```
insert into foo (primary_id) values(14)
insert into foo (a_nother) values(13);
select * from foo;
```

All the best